# iphone app Enter screen

Tags: iphone, uitabbar

I'm in the process of making an app that has a UITabBar at the bottom of it. I want to make an "Enter screen." Basically, when the app starts up, right now the enter screen appears, but the tab bar still shows at the bottom. So if the user presses a tab on the tabbar..and then goes back to the first screen, the enter button is still there. Anybody know a good way around this? I was gonna try to have it so that if the user selected another tab, the enter screen would just go away. Either that or just to have a full screen view over everything and then when enter is pressed, have it close to full screen view. Although, I don't really know how to go about doing either of those. Any ideas?

Chris

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `-viewWillAppear` on your UIViewController subclass to hide your enter screen. It is called every time a tab is selected, on the new tab, just before it is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly... you just want a title screen when your app starts up that never shows again during that session?

If so, just create a file that is a 320x480 image of what you want the screen to look like... save it as a PNG, and name it Default.png.

This image will be shown while your app is loading, and then will disappear when your app is ready to go. No tab bar will show, and you won't need to mess with disposing of any extra ViewControllers.

Comment: This a) Goes directly against the iPhone HIG and b) Doesn't allow for an interactive, or more-than-two-second-long enter screen.